# set ansible-playbook user variable dynamically based on the ec2 distros

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm creating an ansible playbook that goes through a group of AWS EC2 hosts and install some basic packages.  Before the playbook can execute any tasks, the playbook needs to login to each host (2 type of distros AWS Linux or Ubuntu) with correct `user: {{ userXXX }}` this is the part that I'm not too sure how to pass in the correct user login,  it would be either `ec2-user` or `ubuntu`.

```
   - name: setup package agent 
  hosts: ec2_distros_hosts


  user: "{{ ansible_user_id }}"

  roles:
    - role: package_agent_install
```

I was assuming `ansible_user_id` would work based of the reserved variable from ansible but that is not the case here.  I don't want to create 2 separate playbook for different distros, is there an elegant solution to dynamically lookup user login and used as the `user:` ?

Here is the failed cmd with unknown user `ansible-playbook -i inventory/ec2.py agent.yml`

Comment: Does the ec2.py script return any information about the distros? If not, this won't be possible, since Ansible requires access to the hosts to learn about the distro. You can create hosts_vars with the variable `ansible_user` set to the user for each host. But this kind of is pointless, because if you need to cover each host per host_vars a dynamic inventory script doesn't make too much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several ways to accomplish your task:

#### 1. Create ansible user with the same name on every host

If you have one, you can use `user: ansible_user` in your playbook.

#### 2. Tag every host with suitable login_name

You can create a tag (e.g. `login_name`) for every ec2 host and specify user in it. For Ubuntu hosts – ubuntu, for AWS Linux hosts – ec2-user.
After doing so, you can use `user: "{{ec2_tag_login_name}}"` in your playbook – this will take username from login_name tag of the host.

#### 3. Patch the ec2.py script for your needs

It seems there is no decent way to get exact platform name from AMI, but you can use something like this:

```
image_name = getattr(conn.get_image(image_id=getattr(instance,'image_id')),'name')
login_name = 'user'
if 'ubuntu' in image_name:
    login_name = 'ubuntu'
elif 'amzn' in image_name:
    login_name = 'ec2-user'
setattr(instance, 'image_name', image_name)
setattr(instance, 'login_name', login_name)
```

Paste this code just before `self.add_instance(instance, region)` in `ec2.py` with the same indentation. It fetches image name and do some guess work to define login_name. Then you can use `user: "{{ec2_login_name}}"` in your playbook.

Comment: I'm using your option2, which is what I need to have ec2.py generate new tagging as **ec2_tag_login_name** for creating a new tag as `login_name` for either `ubuntu` or `ec2-user` and I was able to properly set up `user: {{ ec2_tag_login_name }}`.   
Other minor issue and might not related to this post,  I wasn't able to get any 'ec2-user' user to establish connection.  
`atal: [ec2-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com] => SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey).
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.`

Comment: Run playbook with `-vvvv` option to check that username used to connect is what you want and check ssh connectivity for that user. Btw, if the answer is helpful, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can set variables based on EC2 instance tags. If you tag instances with the distro name then you can set Ansible's ssh username for each distro via `group_vars` files.

Example `group_vars` file for Ubuntu relative to your playbook: `group_vars/tag_Distro_Ubuntu.yml`

```
---
ansible_user: ubuntu
```

Any instances tagged `Distro: Ubuntu` will connect with the `ubuntu` user. Create a separate `group_vars` file per distro tag to accommodate other distros.