# Define Multiple remote user in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run my playbook on multiple ec2 instances which are running different operating systems.To SSH into the system ansible needs to use a remote username . In AWS cloud, the instance with OS such as REDHAT and Amazon Linux have username ec2-user for login but for instances running UBUNTU we need to use ubuntu as username. So please help me figure out a way to automate this process and help me understand how can I define multiple remote users in a playbook.

Now one way of doing this is we can define it in the host file or in the host_vars file but i am using a dynamic inventory which is generating the IP's of the instances dynamically based on a tag value.

I have tried using a conditional statement in the main playbook file but i guess it is restricted to use something like this in the main file.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set ansible-playbook user varialbe dynamically based on the ec2 distros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38215106/set-ansible-playbook-user-varialbe-dynamically-based-on-the-ec2-distros)

Answer (score 0):

Define tags in your instances when they are created, for example

```
OSType = redhat
```

When you gather your ec2 facts, you can see that now there is a group named

```
"tag_OSType_redhat": [
    "server1",
    "server2",
],
```

Now, you can create a file called `group_vars/tag_OSType_redhat/main.yml` and then add the required username in there.

Comment: It's an already deployed environment, adding tags again is a further overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple hosts and inside them, you can have remote_user: [remote_user] as username and it will work.

eg:

- hosts: host1

  remote_user: "ec2-user"

  tasks:
- hosts: host2

  remote_user: "ubuntu"

  tasks:

Comment: In my case, the inventory is dynamically generated.